# How to arrange binary data columns of a dataframe to the right side?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Assume we have the following dataset :

```
head(data,4)
  age anaemia creatinine_phosphokinase diabetes ejection_fraction high_blood_pressure platelets serum_creatinine
1  49       1                       80        0                30                   1    427000              1.0
2  65       1                       52        0                25                   1    276000              1.3
3  53       0                       63        1                60                   0    368000              0.8
4  50       1                      159        1                30                   0    302000              1.2
  serum_sodium sex smoking time DEATH_EVENT
1          138   0       0   12           0
2          137   0       0   16           0
3          135   1       0   22           0
4          138   0       0   29           0
```

Using `dput` :

```
structure(list(age = c(49, 65, 53, 50), anaemia = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L), creatinine_phosphokinase = c(80L, 52L, 63L, 159L), diabetes = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), ejection_fraction = c(30L, 25L, 60L, 30L), high_blood_pressure = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), platelets = c(427000, 276000, 368000, 302000), serum_creatinine = c(1, 
1.3, 0.8, 1.2), serum_sodium = c(138L, 137L, 135L, 138L), sex = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), smoking = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), time = c(12L, 16L, 
22L, 29L), DEATH_EVENT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm wanting to arrange the binary columns to the right side , so I tried the following :

```
apply(data,2,function(x) { all(na.omit(x) %in% 0:1) })
                     age                  anaemia creatinine_phosphokinase                 diabetes        ejection_fraction 
                   FALSE                     TRUE                    FALSE                     TRUE                    FALSE 
     high_blood_pressure                platelets         serum_creatinine             serum_sodium                      sex 
                    TRUE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                     TRUE 
                 smoking                     time              DEATH_EVENT 
                    TRUE                    FALSE                     TRUE
```

Then :

```
binary_part_indices=as.vector(which(apply(data,2,function(x) { all(na.omit(x) %in% 0:1) })==TRUE))
numerical_part_indices=setdiff(1:13,as.vector(which(apply(data,2,function(x) { all(na.omit(x) %in% 0:1) })==TRUE)))  # ncol(data)=13
data[,c(numerical_part_indices,binary_part_indices)] # result printed
head(data[,c(numerical_part_indices,binary_part_indices)],4)
  age creatinine_phosphokinase ejection_fraction platelets serum_creatinine serum_sodium time anaemia diabetes
1  49                       80                30    427000              1.0          138   12       1        0
2  65                       52                25    276000              1.3          137   16       1        0
3  53                       63                60    368000              0.8          135   22       0        1
4  50                      159                30    302000              1.2          138   29       1        1
  high_blood_pressure sex smoking DEATH_EVENT
1                   1   0       0           0
2                   1   0       0           0
3                   0   1       0           0
4                   0   0       0           0
```

I'm wondering if someone knows a solution ( built-in solution ) that is better ?

Thank you a for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cbind` together with `split.default`

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  unname(
    split.default(
      data,
      sapply(data, function(x) all(na.omit(x) %in% c(0, 1)))
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  age creatinine_phosphokinase ejection_fraction platelets serum_creatinine
1  49                       80                30    427000              1.0
2  65                       52                25    276000              1.3
3  53                       63                60    368000              0.8
4  50                      159                30    302000              1.2
  serum_sodium time anaemia diabetes high_blood_pressure sex smoking
1          138   12       1        0                   1   0       0
2          137   16       1        0                   1   0       0
3          135   22       0        1                   0   1       0
4          138   29       1        1                   0   0       0
  DEATH_EVENT
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
```